# mysqldump running extremly slow

Tags: linux, mysql

I posted this in stackoverflow but it rightly got moved (apologies about duplication!)

I'm testing a new set of db servers on dell m820s running esx5.5 with debian wheezy using ext4 as a VM on each server. Each server has 4 x 400gb SSD in a raid 10 config (the vm's a re stored on the local raid 10 disks)

Our total db size for the main db is 47953 MB (innodb engine).

We use a mysqldump script to backup on the current physical servers (lower spec using debian lenny and ext3 and using LVM) on the same db this dump took about 15 mins to a local nfs store.

Heres the mysqldump part of the backup script for your viewing:

```
mysqldump --opt --triggers --events --routines
```

On the new servers the same backup takes about 45 minutes to the same nfs store (both servers yield the same results also writing locally)

We've tried the following to speed up the process (none improved dump speeds):

```
mysqldump --quick and --single-transction
```

reduced innodb_log_file_size (this was one of the variables which differed so i thought this might be the caused)

We've asked our hosting company to check RAID and disk consistency just as precuation and i'm still waiting results of this.

Heres the cnf of the current/new servers:

Current:

```
[mysqld]
federated
innodb_buffer_pool_size=40G
innodb_log_file_size=256M
innodb_log_buffer_size=6M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT
innodb_file_per_table
transaction-isolation=READ-COMMITTED
max_connections=1000
log-bin=mysql.bin
binlog-format=MIXED
server-id=1
default-storage-engine=InnoDB
thread_cache_size=24
tmp_table_size=128M
max_heap_table_size=128M
long_query_time=3
expire_logs_days=5
net_read_timeout=5000
net_write_timeout=5000
max_allowed_packet=3G
group_concat_max_len=32M
binlog_cache_size=1M
table_open_cache=2048
table_definition_cache=1024
join_buffer_size=1M
innodb_lock_wait_timeout=700
skip-name-resolve
query_cache_size=256M
bind_address=0.0.0.0
```

New

```
[mysqld]
socket=/tmp/mysql.sock
pid-file=/tmp/mysqld.pid
basedir=/usr/local/mysql
datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data
innodb_buffer_pool_size=216G
innodb_io_capacity=200
innodb_log_file_size=256M
innodb_log_buffer_size=12M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT
innodb_file_per_table
transaction-isolation=READ-COMMITTED
max_connections=2000
log-bin=mysql.bin
binlog-format=MIXED
server-id=1
default-storage-engine=InnoDB
thread_cache_size=48
tmp_table_size=384M
max_heap_table_size=384M
long_query_time=3
expire_logs_days=5
net_read_timeout=5000
net_write_timeout=5000
max_allowed_packet=3G
group_concat_max_len=32M
binlog_cache_size=1M
table_open_cache=4728
open_files_limit=9456
table_definition_cache=1024
join_buffer_size=1M
innodb_lock_wait_timeout=700
skip-name-resolve
query_cache_size=128M
bind_address=0.0.0.0
```

Now i have an idea that it might be down to ext4 FS and setting the barrier=0 in /etc/fstab may help this (but this has its caveats).

I also wonder if my buffer pool may be waaaaay to high for the datasize (i've gone with the defacto standard of 70-80% of available ram for buffer pool size).

Any advise on this would be greatly appreciated as i'm a little stumped on this one!

EDIT

Forgot to mention we use mysql 5.5.21 on both servers

Comment: http://serverfault.com/editing-help

Comment: So... why did you change the mysql config between servers?

Comment: You said you asked to your "hosting company"... are then the servers not yours? Are they dedicated to you? Where are you doing the backup? How are io stats and cpu stats during the job? What are the normal average disk read/write perfomances in and outside the virtual machines?

Comment: We changed config as there is a marked difference between server specs, new server 32 cores, 256gb ram, raid 10 ssds debian wheezy ext4, current server 8 cores 48gb ram 15K disk raid 1, and in test application performce this config seemed to provide the best results.  I'm not overly certain if the conf edits should have that much impact on mysqldump though?, maybe innodb_io_capacity but iirc its 200 by default.  Its also worth noting that we're running ysql 5.5.21 on both servers (i'll add this to main post).

Comment: Ah, about the buffer pool... can't really say, of course the more memory you can dedicate to it the better it is, as it will increase performances. Just be sure you got enough memory for the rest of the processes, and that your machine won't start swapping. Normally tuning is done after some time (days, weeks) of real world usage, there are several tools out there (ie mysqltuner) which will nicely present the needed data and give relevant advices to you.

Comment: You dont tell us the esx load too, if too much load, then even your raid10 dont make a difference. How it look like in the performance monitor for IO ? Many third part I know with a sql backend refuse to install in a vm for performance issue.

Comment: @stoned Yeah we ran the mysql tuner and which threw up some of the config changes but all in all it remained pretty similar.  Also system hasn't touched swap yet:

MiB Swap:    16567 total,        0 used,    16567 free,    85590 cached

Comment: @yagmoth555, load on this server is minimal i can't see anything glaringly obvious in vcenter which would indicate a resource bottleneck anywhere.

Comment: @stoned sorry i missed your first post there!

Yes they are dedicated servers exclusive to us, cpu and io stats during the job do not raise any eyebrows.  The backups are performed via mysqldump (running from the local mahcine) this writes to a dedicated nfs store in the same network (we've also tested dumping the db to a local disk with the same results. These servers also occupy the same network as the old servers

Comment: @Slithers how's the wait value when you execute *top* during the backup? Did you check io stats both on the guest and on the host system? What's the RAID controller in your system?

Comment: Wait sits at 0.0 thorughout dump, iostat  looks to be doing nothing tbh but then again i am writing to an nfs store at the moment so i'd expect to see very few writes, vm host stats look normla for a dump of this size too :(.  The raid controller is an PERC H710p with 512mb NV cache

Comment: We've tried dropping the core count on db server from 64 to 32 to eliminate any possible CPU scheduling from vmware or any issues which may be caused by the use of hyper threading, This did not seem to resolve the speed issue.  I am also of the understanding that 5.5.21 mysql will not recognise/utilise more than 16 cores (awiating confirmation on this) so i will be testing this later.

Comment: If I understand correct you are coping mysqldump to nfs store correct? if yes please check slow server nfs mount options, For NFS check **rsize** option and this link for mysqldump optimisation https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#mysqldump-performance-options

Answer (score 2):

Use `max_allowed_packet` beneath `[mysqldump]` directive. Fixed my problem once.

`[mysqldump]
 quick
 max_allowed_packet = 3G`

Comment: Tried this and it did run faster by about 1 minute, but still a LOT slower :(

Comment: max_allowed_packet has a maximum value of 1G and quick is enabled by default

Comment: Seems --network-timeout is also enabled by default and that always sets max_allowed_packet to it's maximum value. So yeah this answer does literally nothing as these options are already on by default.